# Load the .py file and display IPython interactive shell

Tags: python, shell, ipython

In a `.py` file, I have the following content

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

p1 = Point(1, 1)
p2 = Point(1, 1)
set([p1, p2])
```

Maybe it is silly, but I want to load the content of this file into python interactive shell, i.e. `IPython`. I thought I could just insert the line

```
from IPython.terminal import interactiveshell
interactiveshell
```

at the end of the file, but it didn't work. I thought I could use `ipython name_of_the_file.py`, but it didn't work either. I would like to instantiate maybe `p3` without redefine the class in the interactive shell.

**Question :** How could I load the file and display the IPython interactive shell?

### UPDATE

An interesting to know is the `%load` we could use to load the file into the IPython interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you could do `$ ipython -c yourfile.py -i`, where `-c` is execute given file, and `-i` is "do not exit, start the repl" (which is the default unless `-c` is given.

Alternatively if ipython is already started you can use `In[1]: %run -i myfile.py` to run an already existing file in IPython. It is not *exactly* the same as `IPython -c file -i`, and if you came across weird effect look at the options of `%run` with `In[1]: %run?`.

Have also a look at `%autoreload` as well that might be able to watch your file for changes without restarting the IPython shell.